# ajax json demonstration

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, json

part of my page under div#posts is updated according to script results. it is an old fashioned mysql select query with echoing all the resulting tags.

e.g. foreach($output as $view)
      echo "{$view['smthing']}
            
            ";

what my lame programming ass have heard today is that this approach is archaic, and that instead should be used json and ajax functionality to build actual repetitious html structure on client side instead doing it on server side. i know how ajax works, and what json syntax looks like, but still i would appreciate an living example of correlation between the two in questions to boost my project's performance.

many thanks

Comment: You can build the HTML Structure on the serverside and send that down to the client. A lot of times that has better performance than building it on the client. All the client needs to do is set it as innerHTML and it is good to go.

Comment: that is how i have been doing but then team of professionals were trying to explain it to me how that approach is server consuming when you have lot of requests, which is true u will agree. thanks

Comment: +1 for html building server side. Not only better performance but also (re)using the server side templates. building layout is a server task

Comment: `approach is server consuming when you have lot of requests,` But the code also has to build the JSON. Both are strings to the server, what is the difference. Love it! lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is an AJAX call to a service on the server that returns JSON, which, on the client, you merge into a template to create the HTML that you append to the DIV in question.

Dave Ward (Encosia) has some excellent tutorials on that. These might be ASP.NET on the server side, but since you're asking about the JSON, HTML and client side merging I think these will help you:

http://encosia.com/2010/10/05/using-external-templates-with-jquery-templates

http://encosia.com/2010/11/10/composition-with-jquery-templates-why-and-how

http://encosia.com/2010/12/02/jquery-templates-composite-rendering-and-remote-loading

Answer (score 1):

Here is my plan. When you need to update you could send an array of JSON objects. Each JSON object would be one update. So if you need to update a table each JSON object could be a row in the table. Once your javascript has revived the data iterate over the JSON object and process them.

Personally if you have something that works and there are no performance issues i would not see the reason to do something different.